# How to use file contents as command-line arguments?

Tags: linux, bash

I'd like to use arguments from file as command-line arguments for some commands like gcc or ls.

For example `gcc -o output -Wall -Werro`

as file consist of:

> -o output -Wall -Werro

Used for gcc command-line call.

Comment: `gcc $(cat filename.txt)` -- Might need quotes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `xargs`:

```
cat optionsfile | xargs gcc
```

Edit:  I've been downvoted because Laurent doesn't know how `xargs` works, so here's the proof:

```
$ echo "-o output -Wall -Werro" > optionsfile
$ cat optionsfile | xargs -t gcc
gcc -o output -Wall -Werro
i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: no input files
```

The `-t` flag causes the command to be written to `stderr` before executing.

Comment: @Laurent, that is completely false.  The command I wrote executes `gcc -o output -Wall -Werro`.  Try it yourself if you don't believe it.

Comment: Or even "xargs gcc < optionsfile".

Comment: Thank You very much. I tried with pipes before, but I didn't know xargs. It will be helpful in future.

Answer (score 19):

Some programs use the "@" semantics to feed in args from a file
eg. gcc @argfile

Where, for gcc, argfile contains options

```
-ansi
-I/usr/include/mylib
```

This can be nested so that argfile can contain

```
-ansi
-I/usr/include/mylib
@argfile2
```

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options

Comment: +1 Looks like this is the canonical way to do it. Too bad the [UUOCs](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#uuk9letter) won ;)

Comment: I agree - this is the best way to do it, with gcc. The xargs solution follows, in my opinion. It has the added bonus of working with any program.

Comment: This has also the benefit to circumvent the 8196 chars limit in cmd.exe

Comment: You've got bigger problems if you're hitting the 8196 char limit in `cmd`

Answer (score 9):

```
gcc `cat file.with.options`
```

Comment: Note those are backticks, not single quotes.

Answer (score 7):

I recommend using `$()` along with cat:

```
gcc $(cat file)
```

The nice thing about `$()` over backticks (the classic way) is that it is easier to nest one within another:

```
gcc $(cat $(cat filename))
```

Comment: Anything modern enough to understand `$()` syntax also knows how to open and redirect the file itself, avoiding the need for a useless `cat` process.  For example, `gcc $(<filename)` will do the same thing under Bash.

Answer (score 2):

with bash

```
gcc $(<file)
```

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time, command substitution (either through backticks
or $(), as others have pointed out) is fine, but beware of shell
expansion rules. Especially, keep in mind that unquoting is done
*before* and word splitting is done *after* command substitution.

This is not too bad if all your arguments are words but if you
start putting spaces or other special characters that would
normally need to be quoted into your arguments, then you may meet
with strange results (notice the abnormal spacing and quotes in
the output):

```
$ echo "foo 'bar   baz'" >a
$ echo $(cat a)
foo 'bar baz'
```

Quoting the whole command subtitution is not a solution,
obviously, as it would prevent word splitting (hence, your whole
file's content would appear as one long argument instead of many
options), and would do nothing about the quotes.

```
$ echo "$(cat a)"
foo 'bar   baz'
```

One solution around this is to use the eval builtin:

```
$ eval echo "$(cat a)"
foo bar   baz
```

N.B.: echo may not be the best example command here; you might want to
replace it with something else, e.g. the following function:

```
$ f() { echo $#; }
```